# Sentry: sentry.exceptions.InvalidConfiguration: Error 111 connecting to 127.0.0.1:6379. Connection refused

Tags: java, sentry

I am trying to install sentry with the help of [this link](https://docs.sentry.io/server/installation/python/)

Under **Running Migrations** heading after running this command

```
createdb -E utf-8 sentry
```

it asked me to install `postgresql-client-common` i installed it through this command

```
sudo apt install postgresql-client-common
```

after this when i try to run `createdb -E utf-8 sentry` i got this message

```
Warning: No existing local cluster is suitable as a default target. Please see man pg_wrapper(1) how to specify one.
Error: You must install at least one postgresql-client-<version> package
```

and i go the exception after running the command

```
sentry upgrade

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sentry/options/store.py", line 165, in get_store
    value = self.model.objects.get(key=key.name).value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 151, in get
    return self.get_queryset().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 304, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 77, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 857, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 220, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 713, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 785, in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 162, in cursor
    cursor = util.CursorWrapper(self._cursor(), self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sentry/db/postgres/decorators.py", line 44, in inner
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sentry/db/postgres/base.py", line 84, in _cursor
    cursor = super(DatabaseWrapper, self)._cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 132, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 127, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 127, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 115, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 115, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

12:21:31 [ERROR] sentry: option.failed-lookup (key=u'system.url-prefix')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sentry/options/store.py", line 165, in get_store
    value = self.model.objects.get(key=key.name).value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 151, in get
    return self.get_queryset().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 304, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 77, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 857, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 220, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 713, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 785, in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 162, in cursor
    cursor = util.CursorWrapper(self._cursor(), self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sentry/db/postgres/decorators.py", line 44, in inner
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sentry/db/postgres/base.py", line 84, in _cursor
    cursor = super(DatabaseWrapper, self)._cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 132, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 127, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 127, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 115, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 115, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

12:21:31 [INFO] sentry.utils.raven.SentryInternalClient: Not capturing exception due to filters: <class 'django.db.utils.OperationalError'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sentry/options/store.py", line 165, in get_store
    value = self.model.objects.get(key=key.name).value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 151, in get
    return self.get_queryset().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 304, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 77, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 857, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 220, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 713, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 785, in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 162, in cursor
    cursor = util.CursorWrapper(self._cursor(), self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sentry/db/postgres/decorators.py", line 44, in inner
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sentry/db/postgres/base.py", line 84, in _cursor
    cursor = super(DatabaseWrapper, self)._cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 132, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 127, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 127, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 115, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 115, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

12:21:31 [ERROR] sentry: option.failed-lookup (key=u'system.url-prefix')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sentry/options/store.py", line 165, in get_store
    value = self.model.objects.get(key=key.name).value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 151, in get
    return self.get_queryset().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 304, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 77, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 857, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 220, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 713, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 785, in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 162, in cursor
    cursor = util.CursorWrapper(self._cursor(), self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sentry/db/postgres/decorators.py", line 44, in inner
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sentry/db/postgres/base.py", line 84, in _cursor
    cursor = super(DatabaseWrapper, self)._cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 132, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 127, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 127, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 115, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 115, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

12:21:31 [INFO] sentry.utils.raven.SentryInternalClient: Not capturing exception due to filters: <class 'django.db.utils.OperationalError'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sentry/utils/metrics.py", line 64, in worker
    tsdb.incr(tsdb.models.internal, full_key, count=amount)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sentry/utils/services.py", line 91, in <lambda>
    context[key] = (lambda f: lambda *a, **k: getattr(self, f)(*a, **k))(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sentry/tsdb/redis.py", line 214, in incr
    self.incr_multi([(model, key)], timestamp, count, environment_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sentry/tsdb/redis.py", line 239, in incr_multi
    client.hincrby(hash_key, hash_field, count)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redis/client.py", line 1865, in hincrby
    return self.execute_command('HINCRBY', name, key, amount)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rb/clients.py", line 333, in execute_command
    buf = self._get_command_buffer(host_id, args[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rb/clients.py", line 351, in _get_command_buffer
    buf = CommandBuffer(host_id, connect, self.auto_batch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rb/clients.py", line 90, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rb/clients.py", line 109, in connect
    self.connection.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 442, in connect
    raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
ConnectionError: Error 111 connecting to 127.0.0.1:6379. Connection refused.
12:21:31 [ERROR] sentry.errors: Unable to incr internal metric
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sentry/utils/metrics.py", line 64, in worker
    tsdb.incr(tsdb.models.internal, full_key, count=amount)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sentry/utils/services.py", line 91, in <lambda>
    context[key] = (lambda f: lambda *a, **k: getattr(self, f)(*a, **k))(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sentry/tsdb/redis.py", line 214, in incr
    self.incr_multi([(model, key)], timestamp, count, environment_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sentry/tsdb/redis.py", line 239, in incr_multi
    client.hincrby(hash_key, hash_field, count)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redis/client.py", line 1865, in hincrby
    return self.execute_command('HINCRBY', name, key, amount)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rb/clients.py", line 333, in execute_command
    buf = self._get_command_buffer(host_id, args[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rb/clients.py", line 351, in _get_command_buffer
    buf = CommandBuffer(host_id, connect, self.auto_batch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rb/clients.py", line 90, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rb/clients.py", line 109, in connect
    self.connection.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 442, in connect
    raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
ConnectionError: Error 111 connecting to 127.0.0.1:6379. Connection refused.
12:21:31 [ERROR] sentry.errors: Unable to incr internal metric
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/raven/base.py", line 274, in handle_exception
    self.captureException(exc_info=exc_info, level='fatal')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/raven/base.py", line 814, in captureException
    'raven.events.Exception', exc_info=exc_info, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sentry/utils/raven.py", line 46, in capture
    return super(SentryInternalClient, self).capture(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/raven/contrib/django/client.py", line 297, in capture
    result = super(DjangoClient, self).capture(event_type, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/raven/base.py", line 641, in capture
    self.send(**data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sentry/utils/raven.py", line 75, in send
    key = ProjectKey.get_default(settings.SENTRY_PROJECT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sentry/models/projectkey.py", line 121, in get_default
    )[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 132, in __getitem__
    return list(qs)[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 96, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 857, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 220, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 713, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 785, in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 162, in cursor
    cursor = util.CursorWrapper(self._cursor(), self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sentry/db/postgres/decorators.py", line 44, in inner
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sentry/db/postgres/base.py", line 84, in _cursor
    cursor = super(DatabaseWrapper, self)._cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 132, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 127, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 127, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 115, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 115, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?


Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/sentry", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sentry/runner/__init__.py", line 162, in main
    cli(prog_name=get_prog(), obj={}, max_content_width=100)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/click/decorators.py", line 17, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sentry/runner/decorators.py", line 35, in inner
    configure()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sentry/runner/__init__.py", line 125, in configure
    configure(ctx, py, yaml, skip_service_validation)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sentry/runner/settings.py", line 152, in configure
    skip_service_validation=skip_service_validation
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sentry/runner/initializer.py", line 321, in initialize_app
    setup_services(validate=not skip_service_validation)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sentry/runner/initializer.py", line 344, in setup_services
    service.validate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sentry/utils/services.py", line 91, in <lambda>
    context[key] = (lambda f: lambda *a, **k: getattr(self, f)(*a, **k))(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sentry/buffer/redis.py", line 71, in validate
    raise InvalidConfiguration(six.text_type(e))
sentry.exceptions.InvalidConfiguration: Error 111 connecting to 127.0.0.1:6379. Connection refused.
```

i did not changed the contents of these file `config.yml` and `sentry.conf.py` except `mail.backend: 'dummy'` in config.yml

here is the contents of sentry.conf.py

```
import os.path
CONF_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sentry.db.postgres',
        'NAME': 'sentry',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
        'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False,
    }
}
SENTRY_USE_BIG_INTS = True
SENTRY_SINGLE_ORGANIZATION = True
DEBUG = False
SENTRY_CACHE = 'sentry.cache.redis.RedisCache'
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
SENTRY_RATELIMITER = 'sentry.ratelimits.redis.RedisRateLimiter'
SENTRY_BUFFER = 'sentry.buffer.redis.RedisBuffer'
SENTRY_QUOTAS = 'sentry.quotas.redis.RedisQuota'
SENTRY_TSDB = 'sentry.tsdb.redis.RedisTSDB'
SENTRY_DIGESTS = 'sentry.digests.backends.redis.RedisBackend'
SENTRY_WEB_HOST = '0.0.0.0'
SENTRY_WEB_PORT = 9000
SENTRY_WEB_OPTIONS = {
}
```

config.yml

```
mail.backend: 'dummy'  # Use dummy if you want to disable email entirely
system.secret-key: 'iur********************'

redis.clusters:
  default:
    hosts:
      0:
        host: 127.0.0.1
        port: 6379

filestore.backend: 'filesystem'
filestore.options:
  location: '/tmp/sentry-files'
```

i removed the commented parts from both files for the sake of simplification .what might be the cause of this exception? 
i am a beginner in sentry and i am also not familar with `postgresql`

Comment: Did you end up solving this issue in the end?

Comment: no i did not found the solution

Comment: Got it working for me. In my case it was a clean install that was not working. Partly due to aborting mid migrations... :o  But also not giving our VM enough RAM. More ram, and following the README steps exactly did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced into this problem once. The reason is your **Redis server** is **not** running on the background. By default Redis does not run as a daemon.
Since Redis 2.6 it is possible to pass Redis configuration parameters using the command line directly. This is very useful for testing purposes.

1. If you'd like a quick option, run:

`redis-server --daemonize yes`

Check if the process started or not:

`ps aux | grep redis-server`

2. There sre some other ways to change the config for the Redis server. Set daemonize yes in Redis conf file. Set daemonize yes in Redis conf file at `/path/to/redis.conf` Generally it should be there at `/etc/`
   and then trigger redis-server with the conf file as an argument:

`./redis-server /etc/redis.conf`